# Materialize radio buttons conflict with jquery ui buttonset

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, less, materialize

I'm hoping that I am being specific enough about this:

I am designing my website using materializecss. However, this framework only provides classical style radio buttons.
I am instead interested in using the buttonset from jQuery ui as described at the bottom of the page:
https://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/

The problem with that is that the namespaces from materialize and jquery ui seem to collide and i get a mixture of both frameworks as a resulting buttonset.

Could anyone tell me how to avoid this?
I have tried:
Adding namespaces to the respective css files using less and then using them like so
`"<div class="materialize"></div>"`
Which by the way messed up something with the fonts too, as it is now reverted to some not so nice default font

Any help is greatly appreciated

Regards

Comment: I have kind of related problem - when adding jQueryUI js file, the materialize .css Tabs control stop working.. :(

Comment: This is probably not the most useful answer for you right now but we ended up throwing jquery ui and materialize away because its not proper to mix frameworks. Instead we decided to use this: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and stick with it.

Comment: Thank you @fabian-lamba for pointing into right direction. The first solution i found is to "doctor" `materialize.js` and rename some controls eg. `tab` to `tabMaterialize` and corresponding jquery extensions e.g. `$.fn.tab` into `$.fn.tabMaterialize`. However this solved only one problem out of many caused by mixing frameworks. Eventually I have embedded this part of page which required jquery.Ui  as separate page embedded as  `iframe`. Not the best workaround, but seemed the easiest in our case.  True that mixing materialize and jquery.UI would lead to problems...

Comment: I'm glad if this helped you :-)